# Using wildcards with the rmdir or rd command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Let's say there are some folder in the `D:` drive:

```
D:\Air
D:\Abonden
D:\All
D:\Whatever
```

I want to delete all folders starting with "A" (including all subfolders and files). I tried this command:

```
rmdir D:\A* /s /q
```

I get an error, though :(

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The `del` command works with `*`, but I need to delete folders as well.
Is there a way to achieve that via the `rmdir` command?

Answer (score 43):

```
cd c:\temp
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /s /b A*') do rd /s /q %i
```

Use this to test though:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /s /b A*') do echo rd /s /q %i
```

This will pipe out the commands to be run into the command prompt and allows you to see what's going on.

Bear in mind that this will also search subfolders such as "C:\temp\jjj\aaa" and would delete the aaa folder. If you want it to just look at top level folders "C:\temp\aaa", then remove the `"/s"` from the command.

The key to this is the A*, where you would put in your search string. This will accept wildcards such as `aaa*`, `aaa*` and `*aaa*` if you want it to.

Comment: As-is, the command will break if the path/folder name contains space characters.

Comment: Can we add "IF NOT EXIST goto EFO" for A*?

Comment: This works if the path containes space chars: for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /a:d /s /b A*') do rd /s /q "%i"

Comment: I would just like to add that if running this from **within a batch file** then you need to use two percent signs so the command becomes `for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b A*') do rd /s /q %%i`

Comment: no need to use flag 'w/sub' twice :)

Comment: The `/s` option in the embedded `dir` command is redundant, since `rd /s` will remove sub-directories of the `A*` directories. However, `for /d %i in ("A*") do rd /s /q "%~i"` - as described in the answer below - is more elegant, IMHO.

Answer (score 39):

## Deleting folders using wildcards

The `rmdir` / `rd` command alone doesn't support [wildcard characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#File_and_directory_patterns) (that is, `*` and `?`). You can workaround this limitation by wrapping it in a `for` loop.

### Example usage

```
for /d %G in ("X:\A*") do rd /s /q "%~G"
```

**Note** As you're deleting files and folders, you might want to replace the `rd` command with `echo` first. This way you can ensure anything that shouldn't be deleted actually would.

### Multiple patterns

In order to delete multiple folders matching different patterns the syntax is not too different. As @dbenham correctly pointed out, a one-line command is enough. You can also specify different paths:

```
for /d %G in ("X:\A*","Y:\Whatever\B*","Z:\C?D") do rd /s /q "%~G"
```

### Bonus - Checking folder existence

In case you want to check whether specific folders exist, you can use the following command:

```
dir /b /a:d "X:\A*" >nul 2>&1 && echo Folders exist. || echo No folders found.
```

### Further reading

- [for /d - Loop through directory](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [Conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)
- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Comment: Can we add "IF NOT EXIST goto EFO" for A*?

Comment: For example we suppose there is no folder starting with A letter. So command must go for B* . I dont know if I could explain or not :(

Comment: If you want to delete multiple folders starting with a specific letter, you could use something like this in a batch script: `for %%A in (A,B) do for /d /r %%B in ("%%~A*") do rd /s /q "%%~B"`

Comment: You are right but If there wont be A*, we want to know which folder doesnt exist ok? So can we add this? for ex: ===> if not exist "\\%PC%\D$\A*.*" goto :OTHER <===== like this....,

Comment: Under :OTHER commmand will work for B*. I said that is why there may be Win Xp or Win 7, changeble directory ok?

Comment: @serdar Basically you want to delete folders starting with `A` only if they actually exist; if they don't, folders starting with `B` should be deleted instead. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct totaly, but we want to know which folders werent deleted :)

Comment: @serdar I've updated my answer, and I've added a way to check whether some specific folders matching a pattern exist. Let me know if you have further questions or doubts.

Comment: +1 from me. I don't understand the down vote. Though you can do multiple patterns with your simple `FOR /D` and `FOR /D /R` commands. Simply use `in( "A*" "B*" "C?D" )`.

Comment: @dbenham I totally forgot about using multiple groups like that, overlooking such a simple solution. Thanks! Come to think of it, the executed command is `rd /s /q`, and the `/r` parameter isn't required as the subfolders would be deleted anyway. Also, the `for /d` command allows different paths, unlike the `for /d /r` variant. I prefer using commas rather than spaces, although parsing-wise it's the same. As for the downvote, while I was writing my answer another one was posted. Possibly whoever did it felt my answer was redundant or lacking in a way. I've since improved and refined it.

Comment: Actually you do need the `/R` option because the subfolder that matches the mask might be under a parent that does not.

Comment: @dbenham Perhaps I took the question too literally, as the intention was to delete only parent folders matching a certain pattern (and all their subfolders), with no specific requirement to handle such cases - in fact, one might not want to. As noted earlier, a possible drawback of the `/r` option would be the fact you can't handle multiple paths at once. You do make a valid point, though.

Comment: 'SET /P PC=ENTER IP OR HOST NAME
for /d %%a in ("\\%PC%\D$\A*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a"'    working very well :)

Comment: @serdar I'm glad to hear it. If you solved your problem, consider accepting the answer you find the most suitable.

Comment: WARNING: If you want to use this solution in a .bat file, you have to use %%G instead of %G, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file)

Comment: I'm getting `~G" was unexpected at this time.` when am running the command `for /d %G in ("jmeter_output*") do rd /s /q "%~G"` in jenkins pipeline but the command runs fine if I run manually, can someone please help?

Answer (score 24):

How has nobody told the OP about forfiles yet?!

`forfiles /P D:\ /M A* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file"`

```
/P is pathname - where the searching starts
/M is search mask, looking for files that start with A
/C is the command to execute
/S is recursive subfolders (didn't include here, because op didn't ask)
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, should be the accepted one.

Comment: Very good solution and well explained.

Comment: Useful answer :D but IMO `for /d` as in [and31415's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/764348/using-wildcards-with-the-rmdir-or-rd-command#764355) is both cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 20):

adn31415 answer is correct but breaks if you put this in a batch or cmd script. I banged my head for hours till I figured out this is how you use it.

In DOS command window:

```
for /d %G in ("X:\A*") do rd /s /q "%~G"
```

In Batch or cmd script:

```
for /d %%G in ("X:\A*") do rd /s /q "%%~G"
```

If you want to put it into a ".bat" or a ".cmd" file, you need to double the "%" characters.

Comment: You saved my time for the the Batch script!

Comment: no problem dude :) That's why posted the answer as I knew it wasn't obvious and more people are going to run into it.

Comment: Can we add an exclude not to be deleted?

Comment: SET /P PC=ENTER IP OR HOST NAME
for /d %%a in ("\\%PC%\D$\A*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a"
  Does this scritpt work properly?