# I want to remove file & directories from a directory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I had a directory on a windows 2003 server called e:\Transfer.  Once a week I would delete everything within the \transfer directory and then copy the contents from the \transfer directory on another windows 2003 server.

Last month I was told I needed to move my backup directory off the 2003 server onto a 2008 server.  I modified my batch job to point at the new 2008 server and thought that everything was going to work.  After some testing I found out that the "deltree" command no longer worked.  I tried to use the "del" command but it wouldn't delete the directories within the \Transfer directory.  Only the files were deleted.

Is there a way for me to delete the contents of my \Transfer directory without having to delete the directory and recreating it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a folder structure while keeping the parent?](http://superuser.com/q/1001931/354511)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using wildcards with the rmdir or rd command](http://superuser.com/questions/764348/using-wildcards-with-the-rmdir-or-rd-command)

Comment: The proposed duplicate might be useful if someone already knew the answer.  I didn't see a direct answer to this question there.

Answer (score 0):

```
rd /s /q c:\Transfer
```

**/s** - Delete all files and directories
**/q** - No prompting for deleting directories